# Play Framework Configuration

Tags: java, playframework

I am developing a project using the Play framework. Yesterday, 'something' happened and my Play.Configuration object is null after initialisation. I have tried retracing my steps but I am unable to locate the change that I have made that has resulted in the error!

Although Google is usually my friend, I have not been able to find much information on this problem. Does anyone know where I can / should start looking to try to resolve this?

Comment: Hard to help you with so few info... I suppose you looked at your application.conf and try to restore the default conf to see if your app launches without all the things you added?

Comment: @mandubian - I know, I didn't know what information to provide - but anything you would like to know I'll try my best to supply. I have restored to a previous version and I am implementing my changes one by one to see what breaks it. The strange thing is that it is not the config file that is the problem. I think it is something in my code - so I was hoping someone else may have come across a similar issue. The good news is I have narrowed it down to 3 classes. I will post an answer when I work it out.

Comment: I think you choose the right way... it's very difficult to analyse the problem for you in this case... Once you have localized the problem, if you need any help, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Is your code doing anything with Plugins that may have altered the core Play startup routine? I have never seen anything like this before.

Comment: @Codemwnci - Thanks for your suggestion but I have an answer from the play-framework google group - and sadly it was an embarrassing mistake on my part. You can see below for the answer!

Comment: Good answer, and thanks for sharing with the rest of the SO community. I am sure this will be of use to other people in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Morten Kjetland, [who provided this answer on the play-framework google group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/c1e153423d249e96), I have found the reason for the error was as follows:

> It looks like you run the test
>   directly in IntelliJ.
>
> When you do it like this, Play it self
>   is not running - nor is it
>   initialized.
>
> When running tests that use Play
>   features like that you have to run
>   them in play:
>
> "play test" and goto
>   http://localhost:9000/@tests
>
> or "play auto-test"
>
> -Morten

Embarrassingly I did know about @tests url, but I was a little naiive and thought that if I had the Play running then intelliJ would somehow magically find that instance of Play (not sure why I thought that) and conduct the tests accordingly.

Anyway - I hope my mistake will help someone else in the future - and thanks again to the helpful people on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and particularly the [play-framework google group!](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/)